# reiniciar servicio diariamente a una hora concreta

Tags: servicio

Necesito generar un script que reinicie un servicio en un Windows server 2008 a una hora determinada todos los días. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser un script? ¿No te sirve con el Task scheduler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309449/how-to-restart-a-windows-service-using-task-scheduler

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Antonio, re recomiendo leer [*Como Preguntar*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer el [*Recorrido*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

para crear una "tarea programada en windows" tenes que seguir los siguientes pasos:

```
1. Abrir “Programador de tareas” (Task Scheduler) Inicio -> Programas –> Accesorios -> Herramientas del Sistema -> Tareas Programadas.
2. Crear tarea.
3. Darle un nombre y una descripción a dicha tarea.
4. En la pestaña “Acciones”, agregar una nueva, o dejar seleccionada la opción por defecto “Abrir programa” y la caja de texto “Programa/script” seleccionar el navegador favorito (ejemplo: firefox.exe). En la pestaña de acciones podes seleccionar distintos tipos de acciones, selecciona la que te conviene, además podes personalizar las acciones en caso de ser algo muy específico: lo mismo podes hacer en la opcion Programa/Script.
5. En la caja de texto “Argumentos” podes agregar los parametros necesarios en caso de ser necesario.
6. Luego ir a la pestaña “Disparadores” (Triggers) y seleccionar cualquier hora una vez por día (o cualquier frecuencia).
```